# Configuring CloudWatch alarm threshold and period in the console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

In AWS CloudWatch, I have created a **log metric filter** to check a CloudWatch log group for a specific search term (`"ERROR"`) and to consider an instance of this term to be a metric value of "1":

[image]

I *think* this is correct: every time CloudWatch scans the log group and finds an instance of `"ERROR"` I want that to be considered 1 *instance* or occurrence of the issue.

I then created a CloudWatch Alarm on this metric:

[image]

If I understand CloudWatch Alarms, this means I've configured it to "*sound the alarm*" and fire a notification anytime we receive a single `"ERROR"` in the logs inside a given hour of time (60 data points).

So I created this Log Error Alarm and in the Alarm Dashboard I see it as green/ok/active:

[image]

and:

[image]

Two field descriptors in those last 2 screenshots are throwing me off:

- **Threshold**; and
- **Period**

For Threshold, how and where did I configure it inside a given 5 hour span of time?

For Period, how and where did I configure it to scan/fire every 5 minutes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Threshold is 5 hours because you set the metric period to 5 minutes, which means each datapoint covers the span of 5 minutes, and you set it to alarm after 60 datapoints (60 * 5 = 300 minutes, or 5 hours).

To change the period select the alarm and click `Actions -> Modify`. On the edit screen, click `Edit` on the top left, next to the Metric title. There you can change the period to 1 minute.